# How to add all the EVM chains to brownie?

Tags: python, brownie, network

I am able to add particular RPC url for that particular chain for eg. Binace Smart Chain to brownie using "brownie networks add".

But I want to multiple networks to brownie, how can I accomplish that without needing to get RPC url for all separately manually?